# GCD dispatch_sync doesn't finish executing in order

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method which helps me sync my local standardUserDefaults with a Web Service. First, I need to make sure that data has been synced successfully, then I can let the method return. The problem I am currently striving to resolve is that I can't get the GCD to **execute & finish** the tasks in a certain order: **firstly** POSTing to the web service and **secondly** returning.

The problem is that the second dispatch_sync task finishes execution first, then comes the first dispatch_sync task. How to I make sure the execution happens as scheduled? Is this a special case because of the NSURLSessionDataTask?

Thanks a lot!

```
-(void) syncLocalStorageToMMUsersDB:(void(^)(bool success))handler
{
__block bool fb_sync_success = 0;

dispatch_queue_t requestQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.micromorts.request", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);


//if logged in with Facebook, then sync it
if ([_defaults stringForKey:MMFBIdPrefsKey]) {
  // Start NSURLSession
  NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

  // POST parameters
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://THE.URL.GOES.HERE"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  NSString *params = [POST PARAMS GO HERE];
  [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  // NSURLSessionDataTask returns data, response, and error

  NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // Handle response
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSInteger statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
        if(error == nil) {
          if (statusCode == 404) {
              NSLog(@"MMAuth.m :: syncLocalStorageToMMUsersDB FB :: FB User not found");
              fb_sync_success = false;

          } else if (statusCode == 200) {
              NSLog(@"MMAuth.m :: syncLocalStorageToMMUsersDB FB :: Successfully synced ");
              fb_sync_success = true;

          } else {
          NSLog(@"MMAuth.m :: syncLocalStorageToMMUsersDB FB :: Sync fail ");
              fb_sync_success = false;
          }
        }
    }
  ];
  //This should finish EXECUTING first
  dispatch_sync(requestQueue, ^{
      [dataTask resume];
  });
}

//This should finish EXECUTING second
dispatch_sync(requestQueue, ^{

    if (fb_sync_success){
       NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    } else {
       NSLog(@"FAILED");
    }

});
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the first task submitted to `requestQueue` isn't finishing first? Put a log just after the call to `-resume`. I bet you'll see it written before either SUCCESS or FAILED. I think you're assuming that the `-resume` method somehow waits until the task is completed. It doesn't. It just switches it from suspended to not suspended; it allows it to proceed. That switch from suspended to not takes very little time. That's not related to how much time the task itself takes to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the call to `[dataTask resume];` is asynchronous, then that `dispatch_sync()` will return immediately after `-resume` executes and then the subsequent `dispatch_sync()` will be enqueued and executed immediately after (but before the data is loaded).

Move your SUCCESS/FAILED logic into the completion handler block;  that is why completion handlers exist.